# What is int in XML and SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

I am facing some issues in understanding the XML in SQL Server.

I see a xml node like:

```
<InputNumber type="int" min="0" max="100" name="trial node" format="normal">
      <Value>0</Value>
</InputNumber>
```

Here the attribute type says int. I run the below query to get this value present inside it:

```
select
    table.DataXML.value ('(/Parent/InputNumber[1]/Value)[1]', 'int') as "value"
from
    table
```

It returns the value : 0

But if I replace the value to some float say 10.9 or varchar say 'example':

```
UPDATE table
SET DataXML.modify('replace value of (/Parent/InputNumber[1]/Value[1]/text())[1] 
with "example"')
WHERE id = 1
```

It will allow the query to update the field as varchar and if I run the select query again:

```
select
    table.DataXML.value ('(/Parent/InputNumber[1]/Value)[1]', 'int') as "value"
from
    table
```

It will throw an error saying:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'example' to data type int

I do understand the value present in the element is varchar and I am specifying datatype int while retrieving the value, so I would get the error.

But how could I stop or put a check that value inserted is only int not a varchar or float.

Comment: `type="int"` could well be `foo="bar"` so far as XML is concerned - it may be "type" information but not in a representation that you should expect your XML/SQL tools to recognize. For that you'd want an `xsd` describing the schema.

Comment: In one place type="int" it is user-defined attribute but while retrieving we need to give datatype, how to make sure data present is always the type we are retrieving

Comment: You **cannot** ensure that - after all, the XML data is just a big string in the end. What you can do is **validate** your XML against an **XML schema** to ensure those things - e.g. before saving the XML or before transmitting it to a third party. But you cannot really "prevent" other people and their code from writing whatever they like into that attribute....

Comment: Adding that with an xsd, you can create an [XML SCHEMA COLLECTION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-xml-schema-collection-transact-sql) and associate it with the column to validate the xml against the xsd:  `ALTER TABLE dbo.foo ALTER COLUMN DataXML xml(DOCUMENT dbo.ParentSchemaCollection);`